# Shimano Nexus 3 — what anti-rotation washer to use?

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, conversion, dropouts, nexus

As I described in [my previous question](/questions/34487/), I attempted a gradual conversion from a dérailleur to a Shimano Nexus 3 gear hub. I have installed the hub, keeping the dérailleur's pulley for now, with intention to remove it completely when I buy a new chain (this one is worn out anyway). However, I noticed when installed the wheel, the washer doesn't match my dropout, but I'm uncertain which one should I buy instead.

Here's how I have it now:
[image: Dropouts]

Comment: I don't know the physics well, but usually the brake arm is held from under the frame tube, not from it's top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your photo, it looks like you're fine. The load from the hub is being taken on the anti-rotation arm that you've attached to the lateral tubes of your mixte. So the anti-rotation washer (I'm presuming you're talking about the orange washer) is not being loaded.

Also, as described in the responses to your previous question, your dropout is just horizontal enough that you can get about 1-2 cm of movement - enough to tension your chain if you can shorten it, so that you don't need a derailleur.

Comment: Thanks! I was just a bit worried about the unusual position on the anti-rotation arm, so I decided I'd better ask someone with more experience than me :)

Comment: You do have it set up in an unusual place. It's usually on the chain stays but the lats are just as strong on a mixte so there's no reason to choose one over the other. I assume you put it on the lats so as to not interfere with the dynamo power lead to the rear tail light.